# Master detail view using a UITableView in the detail section (iPad)

Tags: ios, uitableview, master-detail

I'm all new to iOS coding, and wanted a small project to learn the language.

My wife asked me to make an app she could use for her work.

I have been looking into the Master/Detail template on iOS and this is something I want to continue with.

Searched the web and looked at a lot of tutorials and comments in this forum, but I have not been able to find anything on how to use this template the way I would like it.

When I click the master section it should then in the detail section load a UITableView with all the properties for selected Item. (A bit like the Settings app on the iPad). If I then select and item in the detail section is should load a new view where I can change the selected property.

If anyone would could give a hint on this, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with the default master/detail template built into xcode.  You can set it for iphone, ipad or universal (both).  I am working my way through a similar question.

Good luck and keep asking good questions here ... the developers here are really great.

Dan